# Sublime Text 2 'Find in Files' open drawer at bottom rather than displaying results in a tab

Tags: sublimetext2

Need help on this one! When I used to use the 'Find in Files' feature it would display the result in a tab so I could go back to reference it later.

For some reason, one day it switched so that the results open up in a drawer at the bottom of the sublime window.

1. This is not ideal because it takes up window real estate.
2. it's aggravating to have to go and toggle the results panel every time I need to reference the results. Would be much easier if it was in a tab.

I've tried looking in all my preferences and nothing seems different so I'm lost on this one.

Answer (score 55):

Found it! Turns out it is the 'Use Buffer' Button on 'Find in Files' looks like I had mistakenly hit that on a search.

Comment: It happened to me today, couldn't find how to get this back.
Just want to point that this answer still works for Sublime Text 3 (Beta build 3083 at least)

Comment: Sublime Text 3 (build 3126), this answer continues to work.

Comment: Sublime 4 still works